# É adequado criar um `CSS Sprite` com imagens de dimensões dispares?

Tags: css

É adequado criar um `CSS Sprite` com imagens de dimensões dispares? Pois tenho exatas 20 imagens onde sua altura e largura são limitadas:

- Altura máxima das imagens é 60px;
- Largura máxima é 100px;

Porem as dimensões de cada imagem varia dentro destas limitações, cada imagem tem em média **3Kb**, estas imagens são exibidas de forma simultânea não cabendo o uso de `AJAX`. Como estas imagens de dimensões diferentes eu não estaria jogando espaço fora **(isso supera o ganho de velocidade da redução de chamadas ao servidor ?)**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*CSS sprite* não é só uma lista de imagens combinadas num só ficheiro. O seu objectivo principal é reduzir o numero de pedidos ao servidor de forma a tornar o carregamento de uma página mais rápido.

Por mais dispares que sejam as dimensões das imagens combinadas numa *sprite*, acaba por ser algo irrelevante para o objectivo por trás do uso da *sprite*.

**Exemplo**

No exemplo em baixo, num só pedido ao servidor estamos a recolher 28 imagens, poupando assim 27 pedidos.

Uma vez que a maioria dos navegadores só realiza 3 pedidos em simultâneo para o mesmo domínio, os 28 ficheiros em separado demorariam bem mais que 1 ficheiro combinado.

Em suma, poupamos cerca de 96% do tempo de espera entre a realização de blocos de 3 pedidos.

[image: Imagem de Exemplo]

## Zonas vazias

A combinação de imagens num só ficheiro para este efeito é geralmente realizada com os formatos .PNG ou .SVG com fundo transparente.

A zona transparente/branca, à qual te referes como "jogando espaço fora"  consiste em informação presente no ficheiro:

- Com fundo transparente: *alpha*

  (r,g,b,a) para componentes Red, Green, Blue e Alpha (Vermelho, Verde, Azul e Opacidade)
- Sem fundo transparente

  (r,g,b) para componentes Red, Green, Blue (Vermelho, Verde, Azul)

Um pixel vazio é registado no ficheiro como `0`, mas é registado e esse registo acaba sempre por ter impacto no tamanho do ficheiro.

Mas esta informação presente no ficheiro tem uma relevância extremamente baixa quando comparada com o número de pedidos poupados ao carregar uma página.

E as áreas registadas a `0` tem um impacto muito superficial no tamanho do ficheiro.

## Optimização

Uma sprite não tem forçosamente que ser uma lista de imagens uma por baixo das outras, nem tem que ser uma lista de imagens lado a lado. Foi dessa forma que tudo começou, mas rapidamente se concluiu que fazendo eficiente de CSS podemos criar *sprites* de forma a optimizar ao máximo o ficheiro gerado.

O truque mais eficaz passa por combinar o uso do `background-position` com o uso de uma `width` e `height` no elemento alvo de forma a que possamos compor a *sprite* da forma mais conveniente para a dimensão <sup>(px)</sup> e tamanho <sup>(kb)</sup> do ficheiro final ficarem o mais reduzias possível:

```css
/* Class para adicionar a sprite ao elemento */
.sprite {
  background-image: url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/brmeta/img/sprites.svg?v=7ecc9f7643b7");
  background-image: url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/brmeta/img/sprites.svg?v=15bbee813d85"), none;
}


/* Class para posicionar a sprite para o elemento page-logo */
.sprite.page-logo {
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
}

/* Formatar elemento */
#hlogo {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}
#hlogo a {
  text-indent: -999em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hlogo">
  <a href="/" class="sprite page-logo">
   Stack Overflow em Português
   <span class="meta-title">meta</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

## Combine imagens utilizando sprites

CSS Sprites é uma técnica antiga porém ainda muito utilizada, ela utilizada durante muito tempo em consoles com baixa memória para guardar grandes quantidades de imagens e informações.

Sempre utilize CSS Sprites onde puder. Se você tem uma grande quantidade de ícones, se você tem uma grande quantidade de imagens decorativas e etc… Junte-as e forme um sprite de imagens que possa ser utilizado por todo o site. Isso diminui a quantidade de requisições que o browser fará no decorrer da navegação do usuário.

Quando utilizamos muitas imagens pequenas e o browser precisa fazer essas requisições juntas, há um acumulo de tarefas, chama-se **[request overhead](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/request?hl=sv)**.

Eu sei que trabalhar com sprites dá trabalho para manter e principalmente criar o sprite inicial. Por isso dá para usar serviços para fazer esse trabalho para você. O **[SpriteMe](http://spriteme.org/)** é um deles.

## O que deixa seu site lento?

Não é somente o peso dos arquivos que interfere na **performance do carregamento** de sua página, toda vez que carregamos um arquivo fazemos uma requisição ao servidor para que transfira o arquivo para o browser do usuário, e o número de requisições feitas pode e interfere na performance do site. E é exatamente sobre essas requisições ao servidor que o **CSS Sprite** vai trabalhar.

## O que é o CSS Sprite?

**CSS Sprite** é uma técnica onde posicionamos diversas imagens que utilizamos no CSS em um mesmo arquivo, e posicionamos esse arquivo de acordo com nossa necessidade utilizando a propriedade **background-position** do CSS, propriedade que faz uso de coordenadas matemáticas semelhantes ao plano cartesiano **(x, y)**.

## Vantagens:

- Uma única requisição ao invés de várias.
- Carrega o arquivo somente uma vez e guarda em cache, assim as demais
  páginas não precisam carregá-lo.

Como Utilizar

Primeiramente precisamos montar nosso arquivo, e para isso devemos nos atentar a um detalhe muito importante, se os elementos **HTML possuem formato retangular**, devemos nos atentar ao posicionamento das imagens dentro do sprite para evitar que sejam mostrados pedaços de imagens que não seriam provenientes daquele pedaço do site.

**O que não devemos fazer na hora de posicionarmos nossas imagens no Sprite.**

[image: O que não devemos fazer na hora de posicionarmos nossas imagens no Sprite.]

**A maneira correta de trabalhár-mos o posicionamento de nossas imagens no Sprite.**

[image: A maneira correta de trabalhár-mos o posicionamento de nossas imagens no Sprite.]

Agora que temos nosso arquivo montado, utilizaremos a propriedade **background-position** para posicioná-lo conforme mostra a imagem a abaixo:

[image: Diagrama de posicioamento da imagem com background-position.]

O **background-position** trabalha com 2 parâmetros: posição do background em X e posição do background em **Y**, onde tanto X pode ser determinado como **Left**, **Center** ou **Right**, e Y pode ser determinado como Top, Center ou Bottom. Tanto **X** como Y podem ser determinados por valores numéricos também, onde devemos lembrar sempre de informar a unidade de medida que estamos utilizando. Veremos agora como é a sintaxe dessa propriedade:

```
Seletor{background-position: PosiçãoX PosiçãoY;}
```

Ou podemos também utilizar a sintaxe reduzida:

```
Seletor{background: cor url(path da imagem) posiçãoX posiçãoY repetição;
```

[ZKDESIGN](http://zkdesign.com.br/tutoriais-e-artigos/otimizando-seu-site-com-css-sprite)
[TABLELESS](http://tableless.com.br/performance-frontend-parte1/)

Answer (score 4):

**O QUE É?**

Pra quem não conhece, essa é uma técnica que se baseia em combinar diversas imagens em uma só, em busca de diminuir o número de requisições HTTP para o servidor. E essa é apenas uma de suas aplicações, no mundo dos games, por exemplo, ela é muito usada para fazer animações.

Sim você pode e deve utilizar para imagens em quaisquer dimensões pois umas das principais funções é redução de requisições.

Fonte: [Tableless](http://tableless.com.br/css-sprites/)

Answer (score 2):

Não dá pra dizer com certeza sem testar dos dois jeitos e ver a diferença de tamanho. Você tem que lembrar que com CSS sprites você vai precisar colocar

```
background-position: 34px 143px;
```

para todos os lugares onde você usar um dos pedaços do sprite. Por outro lado, note que, dependendo da aplicação, as imagens combinadas podem facilmente ocupar um espaço *menor* do que todas as imagens individuais juntas:

1. você só paga uma vez o custo do cabeçalho;
2. se você estiver usando PNGs indexados, você só paga o custo de codificar a paleta da imagem uma vez;
3. o espaço “desperdiçado” (que é a sua preocupação) pode ser e.g. preenchido com a cor branca; regiões da mesma cor são comprimidas **muito** eficientemente pelo PNG.

A título de experimento, eu gerei uma imagem 100% branca, 1600 x 1200 e exportei como PNG e JPG, pelo GIMP. O PNG ocupa 8.3KB; o JPG ocupa 22KB. Se eu passar essa imagem pelo [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/), ele ainda consegue reduzir a imagem pra 365 bytes (!); o [TinyJPG](https://tinyjpg.com/) deixa o arquivo mais gordinho, com 11.6 KB.

Mas mesmo que criar sprites engorde o tamanho total dos arquivos, a finalidade da transformação é reduzir o número de requisições ao servidor. Grosso modo, quando você junta N arquivos você economiza N/2 requisições (já que browsers modernos só fazem duas requisições simultâneas ao mesmo servidor).

Se o seu site for hospedado no exterior, cada uma dessas requisições vai demorar em média 100ms; se juntar os arquivos em um só engordar cada sprite em 1 KB, a transformação ainda faz sentido se o seu usuário conseguir baixar arquivos mais rápido do que 20 KB/s, que é mais ou menos um link de 256 kbps; pra qualquer usuário que não está em conexão discada, ou qualquer conexão EDGE ou melhor, os sprites aceleram o carregamento da página.